# Using SharePoint mobile app on Android error

Tags: 2016, mobile, android

We have an on-premise SharePoint 2016 farm, using an internal root cert answering only on https.  I am trying to use the SharePoint mobile app on my Android mobile phone and I keep getting "There's no network connection" error.  I does have network:  I tried it on the cell network and our wi-fi.  Thoughts?

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I guess you need to join your mobile device to the Intranet same as your SP servers? Either by VPN or using your company's wifi.